# Global Regex not Matching Back to Back Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to put together a regular expression to filter out some data before passing it into a chart engine. I'm running into a problem where parts of the pattern I need to match overlap.

Here's an example:

#### Sample Data

`{name:'race1',data:[0,2,12,20,9]},{name:'race2',data:[9,23,32,19,8]},{name:'race3',data:[1234,1000,1211,980]}`

I need to remove all values below 10, and have tried the following:

```
sampledata.replace(/([,\[])\d([,\]])/g,'$1NO$2')
//Returns {name:'race1',data:[NO,2,12,20,NO]},{name:'race2',data:[NO,23,32,19,NO]},{name:'race3',data:[1234,1000,1211,980]}

sampledata.replace(/(?:[,\[])\d(?:[,\]])/g,'$1NO$2')
//Returns {name:'race1',data:$1NO$22,12,20$1NO$2},{name:'race2',data:$1NO$223,32,19$1NO$2},{name:'race3',data:[1234,1000,1211,980]}
```

but both ignore the second match. I assume this is happening because the first match would be grabbing `[0,` and the second match is getting skipped because I need it to grab `,2,`, but the first comma was already used in the previous match. I'm not sure how to tell it to reuse that portion of the pattern. I tried using the ?: to ignore the group, but that only seems to ignore it from the substitution string list.

Here's what I'm needing the result to be:

```
{name:'race1',data:[NO,NO,12,20,NO]},{name:'race2',data:[NO,23,32,19,NO]},{name:'race3',data:[1234,1000,1211,980]}
```

Comment: Use `.replace(/(\D)\d(?!\d)/g,'$1NO')`

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean to only replace "standalone" 0-9 numbers inside `[...]` that are always comma-separated?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I'll give that a shot. I added an example of what I need back, and will update with a more detailed example of what I'm starting with soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.replace(/([,\[])\d([,\]])/g,'$1NO$2')`, you match and consume a comma or `]` with `([,\]])` pattern, and that char cannot be matched the second time with `([,\[])` during the next iteration.

To replace all digits that are not enclosed with other digits, you may use

```
s = s.replace(/(^|\D)\d(?!\d)/g,'$1NO');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oPqKDV/1).

**Details**

- `(^|\D)` - matches (consumes) and captures into Group 1 start of string (`^`) or any non-digit char (`\D`)
- `\d` - a single digit
- `(?!\d)` - not immediately followed with another digit.

If you plan to only replace such numbers inside square brackets (with `/\[[^\][]+]/g` or - to only match `[...]` with comma-separated digits inside, `/\[([\d,]+)]/g`), first match `[...]` and then replace the digits inside the matches:

```js
var s = "data23:[0,2,12,20,9]";
console.log(s.replace(/\[([\d,]+)]/g, function($0,$1) {
  return "[" + $1.replace(/(^|\D)\d(?!\d)/g, "$1NO") + "]";
}));
```